# Constraining an entire object in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to constrain an entire object (not just the fields of an object) based on some other object. Here is a stripped down version of my production code:

I have the following class:

```
class some_class;
  bit[7:0] some_field;
  bit[3:0] some_other_field;


  // this function would do some complex procedural
  // operations on the fields of the object
  function void do_some_op();
    bit[3:0] tmp = some_field[3:0];
    some_field[3:0] = some_other_field;
    some_other_field = some_field[7:4];
    some_field[7:4] = tmp;
  endfunction

  function some_class some_function(bit some_param);
    some_function = new this;
    $display("foo"); // this print here to see that method is executed

    if (some_param)
      some_function.do_some_op();
  endfunction

  function void print();
    $display("some_field = %x", some_field);
    $display("some_other_field = %x", some_other_field);
  endfunction
endclass // some_class
```

This class contains some integral fields. It also has a method that does some complex procedural on the fields of that class. In the example I've simplified it. I also have another class that returns a new object on which the operation has been performed.

I have another class that operates with `some_class` instances. As per Dave's input I have made it create the objects first (as `randomize()` does not create objects).

```
class some_shuffler;
  rand bit        params[];
  rand some_class objects[];

  constraint size_c {
    params.size() == objects.size() - 1;
    params.size() <= 10;
  };

  constraint shuffle_c {
    // not allowed by standard
    // foreach (params[i])
    //   objects[i+1].some_field == objects[i].some_function(params[i]);

    foreach (params[i])
      objects[i+1].some_field == 
        objects[i].some_function(params[i]).some_field &&
      objects[i+1].some_other_field ==  
        objects[i].some_function(params[i]).some_other_field;
  };

  function new();
    objects = new[10];  // create more objects than needed
    foreach (objects[i])
      objects[i] = new();

    // initialize first object
    objects[0].some_field = 8'hA5;
  endfunction // new

  function void post_randomize();
    foreach (objects[i]) begin
      $display("objects[%0d]:", i);
      objects[i].print();
      $display("");
    end
  endfunction

endclass
```

This class has two arrays, one of operations performed and one of the intermediate states. There is an initial object. On this one, `some_function` is performed and it results in the next object.

This is how I wanted to test it:

```
module top;
  import some_pkg::*;

  initial begin
    static some_shuffler shuffler = new();
    bit rand_ok;
    rand_ok = shuffler.randomize() with {
     params.size() == 1;
    };
    assert (rand_ok);
  end

endmodule
```

When trying to constrain the objects directly I immediately get a constraint violation. The simulator seems to try to make the 2 handles equal. This is anyway forbidden by the standard and I'm not doing it anymore (though a compile failure would have been nice). I've unraveled the constraints as suggested by Dave and Greg (I think doing `some_function().some_field` is non-standard, but it compiles in Questa).

Even now, the `foo` print does not appear on the command line (`some_function()` is not getting executed). What I see is that `objects[1]` contains the initial value (all 0s for both fields).

I can't just generate the list of params and then procedurally randomize the objects for each iteration, because I want to be able to constrain the last object to have a certain value - basically giving the constraint solver the start and the end points and let it figure out the way to get there.

Comment: It might help to explain showing a few examples of what you want the final data structures to look like. And then how you want randomization to work without trying put it into SV syntax.

Comment: @dave_59 I was trying to build a Rubik's cube solver. I made the small example to make the problem more understandable. The idea was to have a dynamic array of cube states and another array of moves. The indexes would represent time steps. The state of a cube at a certain time depends on the move and the state of the previous cube. I wanted to see if the constraint solver can find a solution to a shuffled cube.

Comment: I've worked around the issue by using `pack()` and `unpack()` methods inside my objects and working with streams of bits instead of objects. Something like `cube_stream[i+1] == turn_cube(cube_stream[i].pack, turn[i])`, where `turn_cube()` would create a cube by using `unpack()`.

Comment: It anyway didn't work, because, like you said, the solver treats the inputs of methods as state variables. In the end it was basically just doing silly guesses. It couldn't even solve a cube that was only shuffled 3 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object vs. object constraints are not allowed in SystemVerilog because they are not integral types. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.3:

> - Constraints can be any SystemVerilog expression with variables and constants of integral type (e.g., `bit`, `reg`, `logic`, `integer`, `enum`, `packed struct`).

You can constrain the integral components of class object if the component is a `rand` (ex `obj[1].value == obj[0].value+1;`).

Functions are allowed in constraints, but there limitation. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5.12 *Functions in constraints* for full details.  Limitations include:

- Functions cannot contain `output` or `ref` arguments
- Functions should be automatic and leave no side effects
- The functions arguments have an implicit priority (ex `x<=F(y)` infers `solve y before x`)
- Circular dependencies will result in an error

---

Update:

Looks like the only thing truly being randomized is `params`. The values of `some_field` and some_other_field`are calculations. So it makes more sense to move the loop for shuffling into the`post_randomize` function.

```
constraint size_c {
  params.size() == objects.size() - 1;
  params.size() <= 10;
};

function void postrand_shuffle();
  foreach (params[i])
    objects[i+1] = objects[i].some_function(params[i]);
endfunction

function void post_randomize();
  postrand_shuffle();
  // ... your other post_rand code...
endfunction
```

SystemVerilog's random constraint solver will work when there is at least one solution. However when the solution space is small and difficult to determine or a long chain, simulator performance drops. For these scenarios it is better move the one-to-one sequential calculations into `post_randomize`.

Comment: I've updated the question to take this into account, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like `object[i+1]` is function of `object[i]` and `param[i]`, with no random variation. In this case moving the calculation to `post_randomize` will work better for you. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I would have hoped that the solver does some backtracking. For example, if I already have a constraint on item 2, that it goes back and resolves items 1 and 2 so that the chain satisfies this constraint. It doesn't however, because of the unidirectional nature of method constraints. I might as well just use `post_randomize()`.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of problems with your example code.

- Objects must be constructed first before calling `randomize()`. If
  you know the exact size before calling randomize (like in your
  example), just `new[n]` the dynamic arrays constructing each object
  element first, and remove the size constraints. If the size will be
  random, you need an upper limit constraint on the size. construct the max
  number of objects before calling randomize(), and after randomizing the array, the unused objects will be eliminated.
- Constraint expressions must be integral. You can do `objects[i+1].some_field == objects[i].some_field` but the solver cannot manipulate class handles.
- The return values of functions are treated as state variables. Move these to post_randomize

Comment: Would have been nice to see Questa issue a compile error for the `obj[i] == obj[i]` thing.

Comment: After unrolling the constraints to operate on the fields of the object, I see that `some_function()` is not being called anymore (added a debug print and a print of the entire list of objects). I've updated the question with this info as well.